# Swift PDFviewer Set Display of Digital Certificate

Tags: swift, pdf, certificate

In our PDFView object when I display a PDF that has a Digital certificate applied to the document the digital cert is displayed as a crossed out box like so (the red box was done after using Preview on my Mac):

[image: digital certificate display]

Our app only displays the PDF not modifies it.

Here is the code I am using, you'll see I am only setting the zoom on the document, no other values.

```
var mPdfView: PDFView!
//urlStr comes from our server and is a valid url to get a pdf from our db.

if let url = URL(string: urlStr){
    if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
        mPdfView.document = pdfDocument

        if(pdfScaleFactor > 0.0){
            mPdfView.scaleFactor = pdfScaleFactor
        }

    }
}
```

**Is there a setting or way to define how digital certs are displayed in the PDFView object?**

I have tried looking into the doc for the **PDFView**, **PDFDocument**, and **PDFAnnotation** classes and have not found a good path to either disable a display setting or define how we want the digital certs to be displayed.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: any solution or property you find to disable it?

Comment: Couldn't find a way to remove this, so we ended up setting the size of the Digital Certificate node to 1 x 1. This allowed the image to still show up but the crossed out box was so small it could not be seen. Super cheeky but it works.